# Rendered object visible in eevee but black in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

[image]The rusty pipes are visible in rendered view in eevee and if I make a rendered image. In cycles the pipes are black in both rendered view and rendered image. The rest of the image is visible in both render engines. Render properties - Film – Exposure is set to 1.00. I am not aware of any other setting that could change the outcome. My guess is that I have to change the shading nodes (attached).

Best

Staffan [image]

Comment: Some nodes work differently in eevee than in cycles (or only work in one), I don't know enough about it for a solid answer.  If it were mine I'd troubleshoot by stripping the last Principled BSDF node of individual noodles (starting with the Base Color, put something obviously not-black in that spot) and checking which one's causing the problem, then working back through that branch.

Comment: Here's a list of the nodes that currently only work in eevee: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/materials/nodes_support.html

However, my problem turned out to have a much simpler solution. All I had to do was changing the last node – "Metal" – from eevee to cycles.

Comment: I don't understand your solution from that, but I'm glad to hear you've solved it.  And thanks for the link!

Comment: See screen shot above. After the BSDF node there's another node called Metal. It contains a drop down menu containing the render engines.

Comment: Huh,, is that a Material Output node renamed "Metal"?  I didn't spot that, I always leave it on the default "All".  Why did you change it from All earlier?

Comment: It was set to "eevee" before. "All" works fine too. This is a project I started half a year ago so I don't really remember why I had it set to Eevee.

Comment: The Material Output node is so much a default for me that I barely glanced at it to make sure the noodle was going into the Surface socket.  When you said “the last node – ‘Metal’ ” I was looking at the Metallic socket of the Principled BSDF (what seemed like “the last node” to me) and wondering what you were talking about.  Something to add to my troubleshooting checklist, thx!

Comment: You're obviously way beyond me in Blender. Being a novice, I am happy to contribute to your knowledge.

Comment: Not at all, I'm a perpetual noob myself.  Most of us focus on those parts of Blender suited to our own needs, you could spend years using it to make beautiful stuff, and still be completely ignorant of massive swaths of it that others spent the same years becoming expert in.